# Which way provides a more accurate analysis?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, data-analysis

See example data below:

```
C   34  34  17  12
T1  82  91  29  4
T2  15  44  88  39
T3  23  8   29  30
T4  34  28  6   22
```

I want to see which tests (T) performed better than the control (C).

My two current methods:

1) Perform a sumproduct with the weights. Tests 1 and 2 performed better than the Control.

```
C   31.2
T1  78.2
T2  40.9
T3  14.95
T4  27
```

2) Find out how much better/worse each test is than the control in each category and find the sumproduct of those.  Only Test 4 performed worse.

```
T1  2.41    2.68    1.71    -0.33   |   1.66
T2  -0.44   1.29    5.18    3.25    |   3.75
T3  -0.68   -0.24   1.71    2.50    |   1.21
T4  1.00    -0.82   -0.35   1.83    |   -0.23
```

So my question is, which of these ways is giving me a more accurate result?  Or is there a different way I should be looking at this?

(I'm using Excel 2010)

Comment: I'm not sure.  I'm leaning towards statistically significant, but I'm not sure what the difference between the two is.

Comment: I would compare the tests with the average for each category. But you maight have to know how important is each category, then compare weighted...